# Multidimensional array of zeros in Ruby

Tags: ruby

To create a one-dimensional array, I can write:

```
arr = Array.new(10) { |z| 0 }
#=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But I want to know how to initialize an array in more dimensions, e.g.:

```
#=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

This is just an example. I am trying to understand the general case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily nest multiple [`Array.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-c-new) calls:

```
Array.new(2, 0)
#=> [0, 0]

Array.new(3) { Array.new(2, 0) }
#=> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

Array.new(4) { Array.new(3) { Array.new(2, 0) } }
#=> [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Note that the non-block version, i.e. `Array.new(2, 0)`, should only be used for immutable objects, because the same object will be used for all elements. See the [Common gotchas](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) section for details.

To build an array of arbitrary dimensions, you could use recursion:

```
def multi_array(sizes, default = nil)
  size, *remaining = sizes
  if remaining.empty?
    Array.new(size, default)
  else
    Array.new(size) { multi_array(remaining, default) }
  end
end

multi_array([4, 3, 2], 0)
#=> [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
#    [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Array.new(2, 0) should be [0, 0] at first line

Comment: `Array.new(size) { remaining.empty? ? default : multi_array(remaining, default) }` reads better?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wanted to keep the code simple and as close to the "static" examples as possible.

Comment: By "static", do you mean an immutable `default`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, just my initial examples, i.e. `Array.new(2, 0)`, `Array.new(3) { ... }`. I thought it would be helpful to use exactly these method invocations (passing size and default vs. size and block) in the recursive method.

Answer (score 2):

If by more dimensions you mean an array of array, you could try:

```
arr = Array.new(10){|z| z=Array.new(2,0)}
# => [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0,0]]
```

assuming that your second dimension is `2`.

Comment: You can remove the `|z| z=` part

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "second dimension is 2". Do you mean "the size/length of the array in the second dimension is 2"?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like:

```
Array.new(10, 0).each_slice(2).to_a
# => [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

5.times.map{Array.new(2, 0)}
# => [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand the general case.

```
Array.new(n) # where n is natural number 1..n

#=>[nil, nil, nil]
```

This will create a 1-D Array i:e `One dimension array`.

---

> Let extends further for a multi-dimensional array i:e Two dimension array .

In ruby, every method accepts a block.

```
Array.new(3) do
 Array.new(3)
 end
end
```

Same can be written In online (macro style)  `Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }`

```
[
 [nil, nil, nil], 
 [nil, nil, nil], 
 [nil, nil, nil]
]
```

---

> Further, it can extend to initialize each cell value.

Array.new(3) do
Array.new(3) do
0
end
end

```
[
  [0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0]
]
```

One line micro style `Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) { 0 } }`

> Let extends further three-dimension array.

```
Array.new(2) do
  Array.new(3) do
    Array.new(4) do
      0
    end
  end
end
```

**OR**

The same can be written as micro-style syntax

```
Array.new(2) { Array.new(3) { Array.new(4) } {0} }

[
  [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way, though I feel the deep copy at every level could somehow be simplified:

```
def make_multi(dimensions, default)
  dimensions.reverse.each_with_index.reduce([]) { |a,(d,i)|
    Array.new(d) { i.zero? ? default : Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a)) } }
end

arr = make_multi [4,3,2,2], 0
  #=> [[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]] 

arr[0][0][0][0] = 1
arr
  #=> [[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]],
  #    [[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]] 

arr = make_multi [4,3,2,2], {}
  #=> [[[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]],
  #    [[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]],
  #    [[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]],
  #    [[[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]], [[{}, {}], [{}, {}]]]]

arr[0][0][0][0] = { a: 1 }
arr
  #=> [[[[{:a=>1}, {}...] # all but the first are empty hashes
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it:)

```
arr = Array.new(10, 0)
```

**UPD:** for multidimensional is:

```
arr = Array.new(10, Array.new(2, 0))
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: this is wrong, because each sub-array is the same array. You create in "new" only one array and use the reference to the array as the default value.